# I want my code to show me 4 form2 when i press button2 but it wont why?

Tags: for-loop

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    For i As Integer = 0 To 4
        Me.Hide()
        Form2.Show()
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

'This is my code with problem
I used for loop but the form2 only appears once so i have to keep pressing the button

Comment: *"the form2 only appears once"* - When the form is already being shown, what specifically are you expecting `.Show()` to do?

Comment: I want the from2 to keep reappearing 4 times

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is 4 *different instances* of your form to appear.  (After all, the *same* form can't "appear 4 times" because once it's already visible, it's already visiblt.)  For that you'd need 4 instances of your form.  Something like this:

```
Private form2Instances As New List(Of Form2)

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    For i As Integer = 0 To 4
        Dim form2 As New Form2()
        form2Instances.Add(form2)
        form2.Show()
        i = i + 1
    Next
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

The idea here is that your class is maintaining a *collection* of `Form2` instances, and click your button essentially does a few things:

- Populates that collection with those instances.  (As it's assumed that you'll want to reference them later, outside the scope of this click handler.)
- Shows each of those instances.
- Hides the current form (which only needs to happen once, outside the loop).